# Distinguishing between a variable and a constant

Tags: fortran

Okay, before I start: **I know this is really bad**. I'm asking for a hack for a situation that wouldn't have eventuated if there had been a design agreement that everyone followed. But here is my problem.

I have an enormous Fortran code base with an error reporting routine. The error reporting routine is only called if something weird happened, and it has an integer input: `ErrorCode`. Positive values mean errors and abort, negative values mean warnings and continue.

Here's my problem:

Some people have taken to call the error reporting function like this:

```
ErrorCode = -5
call error_report(ErrorCode)
if (ErrorCode /= 0) stop "Hey, you were supposed to reset ErrorCode"
```

I don't know whether there is any call to that `error_report` that actually expects a negative `ErrorCode` to be reset to 0. All I know is that the current implementation of `error_report` does this, and I don't want to change any functionality.

And other people make it easier on themselves:

```
call error_report(-5)
```

At the moment, in the routine, `ErrorCode` is not declared with any `INTENT`, just so that the code compiles. But of course this only means that whenever a warning is called in the second way, instead of displaying the warning and keeping working, the program segfaults.

I have neither the time nor the authority at the moment to clean up the code properly (normally I'd just set it to `INTENT(INOUT)` and then let the compiler tell me where I need to make changes. But this is not an option at the moment for a variety of reasons.)

Is there any way in which I could write a routine `error_report` that would satisfy both versions? Procedure Overloading? Some method to distinguish between a variable and a constant? Anything?

Comment: No.  You are stuffed.

Comment: Just to be clear, `error_report` is attempting to change the value?  From the description of things it doesn't seem as though that would be what is required, so can't the subroutine just be changed to not redefine the input?  [Naturally, in the more general case IanH's comment is as good as one gets.]

Comment: I haven't verified that any call to `error_report` actually expects the variable to be reset to 0. It's just that the current version of `error_report` does, and I don't dare to change any functionality.

Comment: Well I'm afraid IanH's wise words are correct then. If error_report modifies its argument then calling it in the second way you show above is just plain incorrect.

Comment: Let me be clear: It changes the value if and only if the value is negative. (If it is positive, it terminates execution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea that should work on any *nix system... The main idea is that constant literals are compiled into the binary as symbols, whereas variables are not. 
So if you are using `ld` for linking, it will insert a symbol `_end` at the final position (for both static and dynamic linking). 
This you can (ab)use to check whether a given dummy argument has an address before or after `_end`. In case of a lower address, the actual argument is a constant, otherwise it is a (temporary) variable.

This, however requires some C code:

**addr.c**

```
int isConstant(int *x){
  extern void *_end;
  if ( (void *)x > (void *)&_end ) {
    return 1; // Variable
  } else {
    return 0; // Constant
  }
}
```

**test.F90**

```
program test
  use,intrinsic :: ISO_C_Binding
  interface
    integer(C_INT) function isConstant(a) bind(C, name="isConstant")
      use,intrinsic :: ISO_C_Binding
      integer(C_INT), intent(in) :: a
    end function
  end interface

  integer :: i
  integer,parameter :: ii=2
  i = 1

  print *,isConstant(i)
  print *,isConstant(1)
  print *,isConstant((i))
  print *,isConstant(ii)

end program
```

Compile it as

```
gfortran -Wall -Wextra test.F90 addr.c
```

It will give you:

```
./a.out 
           1
           0
           1
           0
```

<strike>Note that I did not test this with Windows</strike> Tested on Windows using mingw. Use at your own risk.

Please note that the constant expression `(i)` is not definable as per Standard. However, it is created at runtime, and therefore not a symbol. This is apparent in the output. 
However, in the context of the OP, I did not get a segfault when trying to assign it a value.

Comment: I was thinking in this direction, but I didn't know this detail. Does it depend on the executable format?

Comment: @VladimirF Probably... But I successfully tested ELF and PE, I don't think that the OP requires anything else. However, I don't have a compiler at hand that does not use `ld`.

Comment: The issue on Windows is the assumption that code is below stack and heap in memory.  You might get it right 50% of the time.

Comment: @IanH I am not proficient enough in Windows to answer this. Could you elaborate? I just run the tool (+compilation) and so far the decision seems to be 100% right...

Comment: Observed behaviour will depend on platform bitness, operating system version, system settings, flags set in the executable header and perhaps some parameters selected randomly each time the system starts up.  Subject to all those things, as part of address space randomisation support the operating system can decide to load a particular executable image "anywhere" in memory.  As a result the executable image might end up being placed above its initial stack and initial heap, though perhaps use of ld means this capability is disabled.

Comment: Well, at least we got something that might work. I've upvoted this, but I'll leave the question open a little bit longer before accepting it.